# How can I implement caching of sub templates in Kohana?

Tags: php, caching, kohana

I am doing a project in kohana and i am facing a problem in caching a sub-template from a single page.  i am talking about sub-parts of a single page....so one section is static another is dynamic...ive implemented it using nested views, with each independant static part in one view and each dynaminc part in another.

That means a single page my be constructed of a series of nested views some of which contian only static data, others that contain fully dynamic content that must be generated at the time of the request and some dynamically generated content that may be allowed to be semi state....which i would like to keep cached.

Any kohana expert there to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana has a Fragment class for output caching. [Read more](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/fragments) about this class.

Comment: hey.. you solved my problem... thanks man.. you made my day.... i searched and searched but i couldn't find.. actually this is regarding the fragment and i was searching else where.. thanks again. :)